# Why is my google maps marker not showing up?

Tags: javascript, google-maps

My google maps marker isnt showing up. I'm trying to just have a picture of a face as a marker. I can work my own images from there, but I cant get the image of a face to show. The mouseover changes, but the image doesnt show. (Its set on Sydney Australia)

```js
function initMap() {
        var onefivethree = {lat: 53.945574, lng: -1.179075};
        var onefiveone = {lat: 54.958674, lng: -1.169075};
        var Abs1 =   {lat: 51.9583289,  lng: -1.1750136000000566};
        var Abs2 =   {lat: 52.9658919,  lng: -1.153685600000017};

        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          zoom: 15,
          center: onefivethree
        });

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: onefivethree,
          map: map
        });
        var marker2 = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: onefiveone,
          map: map
        });
        var marker3 = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: Abs1,
          map: map,
          //icon: Absimage1
        });
        var marker4 = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: Abs2,
          map: map,
          //icon: Absimage2
        });
        var image = 'https://drive.google.com/open?id=1YtVQYXvFwA4C76WawNBRy2bdKK_KdrkU';
        var beachMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
         position: {lat: -33.890, lng: 151.274},
         map: map,
         icon: image
        });
      }
```

The last marker; beachMarker is the one that should just be a image of a random face!

Thanks

EDIT - Extra code

```js
        var marker4 = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: Abs2,
          map: map,
          icon: 'Capture3.jpg'
        });
```

Comment: It can be viewed (or not) here: http://ryanteaches.com/GPSProject.html

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cattle is not an image.

Comment: Apologies - updated

Comment: Is it possibly anything to do with the size of the image? Do I need to add code to resize it? I thought it was supposed to automatically make it the right size for a marker

Comment: Your map is not centered on the icon.  Once I center the map on the icon and use the link to the image (as @devlin-carnate indicated in his answer), it works for me (I see the image, however, the API does not automatically scale it)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a link to an image.

```
var image = 'https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/full/images/beachflag.png';
        var beachMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
         position: {lat: -33.890, lng: 151.274},
         map: map,
         icon: image
        });
```

Comment: The link I used is a link to an image of a drunk person - https://drive.google.com/open?id=1YtVQYXvFwA4C76WawNBRy2bdKK_KdrkU - I have also tried using the same image locally 'Capture4.jpg' but no luck there either

Comment: @Bob Your link above is not the real link to `drunk` image. You must use a valid image link

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: The real link is: https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/scZfwz_EL70L6HefMFgWzI6MwjRlTdGh1Wp5xla9M73B8a31VSvc2qvuzDl4A_4XQThwRJhm6oVG6hQVWUcG=w1024-h647    .... you can change w1024-h647 with your width height needed

Comment: I uploaded the image to github as Capture3.jpg and then tried to link it in as seen in the edited code at the bottom - that doesnt seem to work either?

Comment: If the image is on GitHub or any server other than the one your code is loaded from, you will need to use the full URL to the image, not just `"Capture3.jpg"`.